# Only single beep for a series of bells in PuTTY

Tags: linux, windows, shell, putty, bell

After typing  `echo -ne '\a' && echo -ne '\a'` in PuTTY session only single beep is being produced on local computer instead of two beeps.
What is the reason?

In PuTTY settings for this session, *Beep using the PC speaker* radio is checked and *Bell is temporarily disabled when over-used* checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Maybe the beeps are actually two, but very close to each other. Try echo -ne '\a' && sleep 1 && echo -ne '\a', to see if that's the case

Comment: @Bruno9779 Inserting `sleep` makes it work indeed. *Maybe the beeps are actually two* – if you mean speaker actually produces two beeps but very quickly then I don't think that's the case. I guess what happens is that `echo` is in fact asynchronous and returns before the first beep is finished and then the second `echo` is kind of lost as the first call is not really finished at the OS level. However I can't find any confirmation for this theory.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. && waits for the first command to exit successfully before executing the following one

Comment: See PuTTY's source code. In case of PC speaker, there's required minimum 50ms between beeps - https://github.com/github/putty/blob/7003b43963aef6cdf2841c2a882a684025f1d806/windows/window.c#L5566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See PuTTY's source code for answer. In case of "PC speaker", it beeps only if at least 50ms elapsed from last beep.
https://github.com/github/putty/blob/master/windows/window.c#L5566

```
if (mode == BELL_PCSPEAKER) {
    ...
    beepdiff = GetTickCount() - lastbeep;
    if (beepdiff >= 0 && beepdiff < 50)
        return;
```